# Trigger is not firing

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles, datatrigger

Been doing trial and error on this all day. Thought it might be better to post here and get some feedback on whether I am doing this the right way or not. I am just trying to change the TextBlock ToolTip text when the radio button is checked.

**Edit:** Figured it out... I applied the Trigger to the DataTemplate instead of the TextBlock itself. (See answer)

Comment: On a side-note, you could have done the same thing in the TextBlock's style.

Answer (score 4):

If you set the text locally the trigger will not be able to change the value due to [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Move the default text into the style:

```
<!-- There are still issues with this -->
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SIMULATOR_CONTROL_BLADE_DATA.CONTROL_BLADE_ASSEMBLY.REACTOR_CORE_COORDINATE.RCC_REACTOR_Y}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding radSimulator, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Binding Path="SIMULATOR_CONTROL_BLADE_DATA.CONTROL_BLADE_ASSEMBLY.REACTOR_CORE_COORDINATE.RCC_MODEL_Y"></Binding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

This binding is broken:

```xml
Binding="{Binding radSimulator, Path=IsChecked}"
```

This means you set the path twice because the string entered without any property-name will be used as path (see [the respective constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx) of [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx)), should this possibly be this?

```xml
Binding="{Binding ElementName=radSimulator, Path=IsChecked}"
```

Comment: even though I am binding the text to a linq entity path?

Comment: Doesn't matter what you bind to, also one binding seems broken.